# Does the isomorphism $\text{Ann}^M(1-ab)\cong \left(\text{Ann}^M(1-ab)\right)a$ always hold?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, free-modules, module-isomorphism, bimodules

Let $R$ be a  ring with unity and  $a,b\in R$.   For a right $R$ module $M$, define $\text{Ann}^M(r)=\{m\in M:mr=0\}$ as a right $R$-module:

My question is, does the isomorphism  $\text{Ann}^M(1-ab)\cong \left(\text{Ann}^M(1-ab)\right)a$ always hold?

I believe it holds if $a$ is a unit element in $R$.  My attempt for the proof is:  Define two morphisms $f:\text{Ann}^M(1-ab)\to \left(\text{Ann}^M(1-ab)\right)a$ by $f(m)=ma$ and $g:\left(\text{Ann}^M(1-ab)\right)a\to \text{Ann}^M(1-ab)$ by $g(ma)=m$.  My deduction is $fg=1$ and $gf=1$ and so $f$ is an isomorphism.  However, I am not sure whether the isomorphism exists.

Comment: You need to show g is well defined.